# Deploying django website only for local network?

Tags: apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

I developed a website with Django and I am deploying it with apache and mod-wsgi (as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)). The catch is that I want to make sure that this website is accessible only on my local network.

On the same server, I will publish another website, probably with Apache too, that *will* be accessible to the Internet.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2):

Either use the [Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) from Apache to allow only internal IPs or use a middleware like [Django IP Restrict](http://django-iprestrict.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).